# I have a problem with this error output = Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-x0egt255/mysqlclient/

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, devops

I'm trying to create a pipeline for code automation deployment to the openshift cluster, but when the pipeline were on the installing requirement stage there's always an error on installing mysql, is there any chance that it is a bug or my code were false? Any help or feedback would be great, Thanks!

This is my jenkinsfile and i'm using mysqlclient version 1.4.2.post1 on the requirements.txt

```
pipeline {
    agent {
    node {label 'python'}
    }
    environment {
        APPLICATION_NAME = 'xxx'
        GIT_REPO="https://xxx.git"
        GIT_BRANCH="master"
        STAGE_TAG = "promoteToQA"
        DEV_PROJECT = "dev"
        STAGE_PROJECT = "stage"
        TEMPLATE_NAME = "xxx"
        ARTIFACT_FOLDER = "target"
        PORT = 8080;
    }
    stages {
        stage('Get Latest Code') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxx', passwordVariable: 'xxx', usernameVariable: 'xxx')]) {
                        sh('git pull https://${xxx}:${xxx}@xxx')
                    }
            }
        }
        stage ("Install Dependencies") {
            steps {
                sh """
                pip install virtualenv
                virtualenv --no-site-packages .
                source bin/activate
                pip install -r requirements.txt
                deactivate
                """
            }
        }
```

The error output were always like this

```
Collecting mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz (85kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x0egt255/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x0egt255/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 51, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x0egt255/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-x0egt255/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: "mysql_config not found" You should install it.

Comment: i'm using mac so do i need to install it locally using homebrew? i'm new on this devops territory